# configure .net runtime 2.0 error reporting

Tags: c#, .net, exception

On some machines, when a managed application (.NET) throws an exception that doesn't get handled (read: crashes), I get a "Unhandled Exception" dialog that comes from the .NET runtime/CLR. That message also gets logged in the Windows Event log.
Figure 6 on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc793966.aspx#id0070033 shows an entry that gets logged in the Application Event Log.

My problem is that on my current machine, this doesn't happen, and I need it to happen. So is this configurable somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the source code of your application, you can actally trap all unhandled exceptions by subscribing to the appdomain.currentdomain.unhandledexception event. This way you can handle application crashes more gracefully and you can log exceptions where ever u want to.

Comment: cool :) wasn't aware of appdomain.currentdomain.unhandledexception :)

Comment: Thanks, your answer is usefull, but I'm really looking for an option to let the CLR do the handling/logging.

Answer (score 0):

Try use for logging error in AppDomain.UnhandledException [log4net.](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)